# Use dictionary in tf.function input_signature in Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I am using Tensorflow 2.0 and facing the following situation:

```
@tf.function
def my_fn(items):
    .... #do stuff
    return
```

If items is a dict of Tensors like for example:

```
item1 = tf.zeros([1, 1])
item2 = tf.zeros(1)
items = {"item1": item1, "item2": item2}
```

Is there a way of using input_signature argument of tf.function so I can force tf2 to avoid creating multiple graphs when item1 is for example `tf.zeros([2,1])` ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The input signature has to be a list, but elements in the list can be dictionaries or lists of Tensor Specs. In your case I would try: (the `name` attributes are optional)

```
signature_dict = { "item1": tf.TensorSpec(shape=[2], dtype=tf.int32, name="item1"),
                   "item2": tf.TensorSpec(shape=[], dtype=tf.int32, name="item2") } 
              

# don't forget the brackets around the 'signature_dict'
@tf.function(input_signature = [signature_dict])
def my_fn(items):
    .... # do stuff
    return

# calling the TensorFlow function
my_fun(items)
```

However, if you want to call a particular concrete function created by `my_fn`, you have to unpack the dictionary. You also have to provide the `name` attribute in `tf.TensorSpec`.

```
# creating a concrete function with an input signature as before but without
# brackets and with mandatory 'name' attributes in the TensorSpecs 
my_concrete_fn = my_fn.get_concrete_function(signature_dict)
                                             
# calling the concrete function with the unpacking operator
my_concrete_fn(**items)
```

This is annoying but should be resolved in TensorFlow 2.3. (see the end of the TF Guide to 'Concrete functions')